Add a Custom Billing Field to WooCommerce Checkout, Order Meta, and User Meta
I have implemented a custom WooCommerce checkout field to collect a Tax Exempt Number in the billing section. This field's value is stored in the user meta upon checkout to facilitate future orders.
The functionality includes:

Displaying the field on the thank you page and the "View Order" page (/my-account/view-order/#/) for logged-in customers.

Including the field value in emails sent to guests, customers, and admins.

Allowing customers to edit the field value in the Addresses section of their account (/my-account/edit-address/billing/).

Allowing admins to edit the field value on the order edit page and the WordPress user edit page.

Loading the field value via AJAX when a customer is selected for a manual order.


<?php

/**
 * WooCommerce: Custom Billing Checkout Field (Tax Exempt #)
 */
function custom_checkout_fields_settings() {
    $text_domain = 'woocommerce';
    return array(
        'tax_exempt_number' => __('Tax Exempt #', $text_domain),
    );
}

// Add Tax Exempt # Field to Checkout and My Account Edit Address
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_billing_field' );
function custom_billing_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_tax_exempt_number'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Tax Exempt #', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Enter Your Tax Exempt Number', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'priority'    => 35,
    );
    return $fields;
}

// Display Tax Exempt # Field on admin edit order page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'admin_single_order_custom_addresses_fields' );
function admin_single_order_custom_addresses_fields( $fields ) {
    $settings = custom_checkout_fields_settings();

    foreach ( $settings as $field_key => $field_label ) {
        $fields[$field_key] = array(
            'label'         => $field_label,
            'show'          => '0',
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-field-wide',
        );
    }
    return $fields;
}

// Load Tax Exempt # Field data as customer billing address field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_get_customer_details', 'add_custom_fields_to_ajax_customer_details', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_fields_to_ajax_customer_details( $data, $customer, $user_id ) {
    $data['billing']['tax_exempt_number'] = $customer->get_meta('billing_tax_exempt_number');
    return $data;
}


// Add Tax Exempt # Field to WooCommerce billing address in user profile
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields' , 'user_profile_custom_fields' );
function user_profile_custom_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['fields']['billing_tax_exempt_number'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Tax Exempt #', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => '',
    );
    return $fields;
}

// Display Tax Exempt # Field on email notifications
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','display_custom_fields_on_emails_notifications', 30, 4 );
function display_custom_fields_on_emails_notifications( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $settings = custom_checkout_fields_settings(); // Load settings
    foreach ( $settings as $field_key => $field_label ) {
        $meta_value = $order->get_meta('_billing_'.$field_key);
        if ( ! empty($meta_value) ) {
            echo '<div><strong>' . $field_label . ':' . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $meta_value . '</span></div>';
        }
    }
}

// Save the Tax Exempt # Field from the admin order edit screen and update the user meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'save_custom_billing_field_and_update_user_meta', 45, 2 );

function save_custom_billing_field_and_update_user_meta( $order_id, $post ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $settings = custom_checkout_fields_settings(); // Load Settings
    foreach ( $settings as $field_key => $field_label ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['_billing_' . $field_key] ) ) {
            // Save the order meta data
            $order->update_meta_data('_billing_' . $field_key, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_billing_' . $field_key] ));
            // Also update the user meta data if a customer ID is present
            if ( $order->get_customer_id() ) {
                update_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_' . $field_key, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_billing_' . $field_key] ) );
            }
        }
    }
    $order->save_meta_data();
}


// Save the Tax Exempt # Field (once order is placed)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_custom_billing_field_on_create_order', 20, 2 );
function save_custom_billing_field_on_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_tax_exempt_number'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['billing_tax_exempt_number'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_tax_exempt_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_tax_exempt_number'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_tax_exempt_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_tax_exempt_number'] ) );
    }
}

// Display Tax Exempt # Field in order details customer section using user meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', 'display_tax_exempt_number_in_order_details' );
function display_tax_exempt_number_in_order_details( $order ) {
    // Get the user ID from the order
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    // Get the tax exempt number from the user meta
    $tax_exempt_number = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_tax_exempt_number', true );
    // If it exists, display the tax exempt #
    if ( ! empty( $tax_exempt_number ) ) {
        echo '<p style="font-style:italic;"><strong>' . __('Tax Exempt #:', 'woocommerce') . '</strong> ' . esc_html( $tax_exempt_number ) . '</p>';
    }
}

